# Как загрузить файл изображения в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Вопрос в следующем - необходимо загрузить изображения в формате .jpg в таблицу базы данных MySQL. Создал таблицу с колонкой images типа BLOB. Попытался загрузить изображение при помощи запроса
LOAD DATA INFILE 'DSC_0010mm.jpg' INTO TABLE tb1 (images);

Выбивает ошибку - Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Подскажите, как сформулировать корректный SQL-запрос и как изменить режим secure-file-priv.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

### C#

Как я делаю:
Создаю в таблице поле photo с типом `varbinary(max)` или `image`.
Дальше через класс `OpenFileDialog` получаю путь к выбранному изображению.
Дальше конвертирую изображение в массив байтов, потому что поле photo ожидает как раз его.
Дальше через любую доступную вам технологию для доступа работы с базой данных через update-запрос обновите поля.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, попробую записать изображения в виде битового потока программно. Но кто нибудь может подсказать, как загрузить изображения в таблицу непосредственно инструментами MySQL, а не обходным путём через язык программирования?